# How to assign arguments to the super method of a child constructor?

Tags: java

I have parent class  Person  and a subclass SubPerson

```
//Parent class
public class Person {
    protected String Name;
    protected String Email;

    public Person(String name, String email) {
        Name = name;
        Email = email;

    }
```

```
//Child Class

public class SubPerson extends Person {

    private String Id;
    private String Telephone;


    public SubPerson(){

    }
    public SubPerson(String name, String email, String id, String tel) {
        super(nombre, email, String Id, String );
        Id = id;
        Telephone = tel;

    }
```

How should I invoke the constructor of the child class in another block of code?
My attempt is the following

```
// ... Other Methods
// This method stores the value in a database
public String RegisterSubClass(String name, String email, String id, String tel){
super(name, email); //This error says that super expected 0 parameters

 }
```

How can I call the constructor in a way that allows me to assign the parameters that belong to the parent and the parameters that belong to the child?

Thanks

Comment: What is `RegisterSubClass`? I assume it is just a class, which inherits from `Object`, so it's parent doesn't take two parameters. Calling `SubPerson`'s constructor will pass the parameters up to its parent. It is `SubPerson`'s responsibility to ensure the correct parameters are passed to its parent.

Comment: `super(nombre, email, String Id, String );` that just cannot compile, and there is a brace missing too. Please make sure that you provide working code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can invoke the parent class constructor from another method in child, it has to be the first call in the child class constructor. However you can call other methods in the base class that set the values for variables.